# CKEDITOR 4.x - How to keep height and width in TD element

Tags: ckeditor

I have this code:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td  colspan="1" height="20" width="658">A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="1" width="658">B</td>
  </tr>   
 </table>
```

CKEDITOR convert it in

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">B</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How I can keep height and width?
Some mailers program do not like style attribute in TD element.

Comment: Just curious, why not use the style instead of the direct attribute?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED
I have use the  config property  **[config.allowedContent](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/datafiltering.html)**

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more-- specifically, once td th[width] attribute is allowed (and maybe {width} style property disallowed, how does the CKEditor UI "Cell Properties" dialog know to automatically start using the width attribute instead of the style property?

Answer (score 0):

In the ckeditor, right-click the cell you want to customize. Choose cell and then cell properties. There you can set the desire width and height of the cell.

Comment: Yes, sure but I don't want the "style" attribute, I need to keep height="xx" and width="xx" attributes